# Generate SQL Update Statement

Tags: t-sql, sql-update

Anyone knows of a method to generate a generic UPDATE statement for table.
I would like to pass a tablename as parameter, and the result should be an UPDATE statement like:

```
UPDATE [LinkedServer].[dbo].mytable foreign
SET Col2 = local.Col2, 
    Col3 = local.Col3
FROM mytable local
WHERE foreign.Col1 =  local.Col1
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'the result should be an update statement'? Do you want it printed as a text or executed as a result? Either way you could create an SP that takes the param, constructs and runs the statement or am I missing something?

Comment: Either way doesn't matter.  Eventually the statement should be executed.  I was hoping to not write the SP myself but use one of someone else.  But I'm already half way now.  Will post it when I'm finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works now:

Note: My Primary keys are created as Unique Constraints with the name 'PrimaryKey'.

```
/*------------------------------------------------*/
/*        Create generic UPDATE statement         */
/*------------------------------------------------*/
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects 
           WHERE name = 'GetUpdateStatement' AND type = 'FN')
   DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetUpdateStatement
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetUpdateStatement
    (@TableName varchar(40),
     @LinkedServer varchar(100))    
    RETURNS varChar(max)
    --WITH ENCRYPTION
     AS 
BEGIN

DECLARE @sql varchar(max) = ''
DECLARE @where varchar(max) = ''

SET @sql = 'UPDATE [' + @LinkedServer + '].[dbo].[' + @TableName + '] ' +
           'SET '
--Add all the columns
DECLARE C CURSOR FOR
SELECT Column_Name
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName
  AND Column_Name <> 'Systimestamp'
ORDER BY ordinal_position
OPEN C

DECLARE @colname varchar(40)
DECLARE @isPK smallint
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @colname

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @isPK = (SELECT 1
                 FROM sys.indexes MyIndex
                 INNER JOIN sys.index_columns IndexColumns 
                    ON  MyIndex.index_id = IndexColumns.index_id
                    AND MyIndex.object_id = IndexColumns.object_id 
                 INNER JOIN sys.columns Columns
                    ON  Columns.column_id = IndexColumns.column_id 
                    AND IndexColumns.object_id = Columns.object_id 
                 INNER JOIN sys.objects Objects ON Objects.object_id = Columns.object_id 
                 WHERE Columns.name = @colname
                   AND Objects.name = @TableName
                   AND MyIndex.Name='PrimaryKey')
    IF @isPK = 1
        SET @where = @where + '[' + @LinkedServer + '].[dbo].[' + @TableName + '].' + @colname + ' = Source.' + @colname + ' AND '
    ELSE
        SET @sql = @sql + @colname + ' = Source.' + @colname + ', '

    FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @colname
END
CLOSE C
DEALLOCATE C
--Remove the last comma
SET @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql) - 1) + ' '
SET @where = LEFT(@where, LEN(@where) - 4) 

--Add FROM
SET @sql = @sql + 'FROM ' + @TableName + ' AS Source '

--Add WHERE of the PK's
SET @sql = @sql + 'WHERE ' + @where

RETURN @sql

END
```